# How to reload focus on form controls (dockPanels)

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have one Form with four dockPanels

- dock_1
- dock_2
- dock_3
- dock_4

I want to focus on specific dockPanel by changing theirs 'tabIndex'. For dockPanel which should be focused I set tabIndex on 0, rest of dockPanels' indexes I increase.

I need control it inside method to be able trigger changes when I need it. I can set it inside constructor and during form first initialization focus can be set correct but it's not what I need.

The problem is that I can't force realod focus on form so when I change tabIndexes nothing happened.

Do you know how to trigger:

System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl()

It should reload focus inside the form but I'm not able to trigger it. 
I tried solutions similar to:   myForm.Select() but without any results.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what your goal is.  Are you re-ordering the TabIndex and then trying to give the focus to the  dockPanel that has `TabIndex == 0`?

Comment: Yes. When you set tabIndex = 0 for eg. dock_1 Inside constructor focus will be on dock_1. But It works only Inside constructor and first form draw. I can't redraw focus after that when eg I set tabIndex=0 for dock_3 and tabIndex for rest dockPanel I increase. After this change focus should be on dock3. It how It works. But i don't know How to refocus manually / redraw form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TabIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is not applicable for dock panels.
Use the [DockManager.ActivePanel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockManager_ActivePaneltopic) property to get or set the currently **active** dock panel:

```
dockManager1.ActivePanel = dockPanel1;
```

The **active** dock panel is the one that has focus or contains a control that has focus.
When the active dock panel is changed the [DockManager.ActivePanelChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockManager_ActivePanelChangedtopic) event is fired.